# Как переключиться на следующий элемент массива в цикле foreach PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Например, чтобы вывести 2 элемента внутри одного блока:

```
$array = ['foo','bar','car','bee'];

foo, bar

car, bee
```

Comment: @KirillKorushkin вы неправильно изменили вопрос. второй блок `bar-car`

Comment: вам ведь надо не просто на пары разбить? такую логику как вы придумали в foreach не обернуть. ибо на следующей итерации получите повтор. Опишите критерии объединения элементов, иначе не ясно вообще что вы хотите

Comment: для ассоциативного
foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if($k == "foo" && $k == "car")
    {
       echo $v;
    }
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
$v;//текущий элемент
$arr[$k+1];//следующий элемент
}
```

P.S.: Подходит только для индексированых масивов (для ассоциативных не подойдет)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать срез массива `array_slice()`, ну и не обойтись без какого-то условия, проверяющего существование переменной. `foreach()` наверное не самый удачный инструмент для подобных задач.

```
$array = ['foo', 'bar', 'car', 'bee'];

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $slice = array_slice($array, $k * 2, 2);
    !$slice ?:  print join(', ', $slice) . '<br>';
}
```

**UPD**: Подправил код с учётом правки в первом посту.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов решения:
через счетчик и условный оператор if

```
         $i = 0;
         $array = ['foo','bar','car','bee'];
         foreach ($array as $item){
            if($i <= 2){
               break;
            }
            echo $item;
            $i++;
        }
```

Можно разделением массива функцией array_chunk():(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$array = array_chunk($array, 2)
foreach($array[0] as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще использовать индексы массива через array_keys, и проходить по ним через

```
for($index = 0; $index < count($array_keys = array_keys($array)); $index++) {echo $array[$array_keys[$index]]; echo $array[$array_keys[$index+1]]; }
```

Само собой нужно добавить проверку на существование индекса ...